# How To Access A Shared Property Of A Class Passed As A Type Parameter

Tags: vb.net, class, generics, properties, type-parameter

I'm trying to access a shared property of a class passed as a parameter to a type-parametrised procedure. The *reason* why I'm doing this is so I can embed the various API call endpoints (among other class-specific things) as properties within the class itself. I've read some similar SO posts but nothing is close enough to be sure that it isn’t possible (which I think is likely).

Below is the essence of the structure - there's some pseudo code towards the end:

```
MustInherit Class BaseClass

  Shared Property Endpoint As String
End Class

Class Person
  Inherits BaseClass

  Property Age As Integer
  Property Name As String
  Sub New()
    _Endpoint = "/GetPerson"
  End Sub
End Class

Class Event
  Inherits BaseClass

  Property When As Date
  Property Type As String
  Sub New()
    _Endpoint = "/GetEvent"
  End Sub
End Class

Function Retrieve(T As BaseClass)(Id As String) As T

  Dim oResp As HttpResponse = MakeGetCall(T.Endpoint, Id) <- T.Endpoint throws a compile error
  Return Deserialize(Of T)(oResp.Content)
End Function

Dim oPerson As Person = Retrieve(Of Person)("123")
Dim oEvent As Event = Retrieve(Of Event)("123")
```

To my tiny mind, I would have thought that, since `T`’s base class is `BaseClass` which contains the property `Endpoint`, I’d be ok. But seemingly not.

I've tried a fair few things from here on SO and other places to overcome this to no avail. Yes, I realize I could perform some kind of endpoint look-up based on the type of `T` but the above represents a very clean solution and I’d like to get it to work if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Given that you have already tied that method to the `BaseClass` type by using it as a constraint, what point is there to trying to avoid simply getting `BaseClass.EndPoint` within the method?

Comment: Shared properties on the base class will change across all subclasses! In other words, `Person.EndPoint` will always be the same as `Event.EndPoint` because the value is only stored in the base class.

Comment: @jmcilhinney `BaseClass.Endpoint` is null when `MakeGetCall` line is executed. `Person/Event` is only instantiated when when deserialization occurs on the `Return` line. But you got me thinking. I instantiated a dummy `Record` object before the call: `Dim oDummy As BaseClass = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()` and that allowed me to use your suggestion. It's a bit messy but better than the alternatives. Thanks.

Comment: @SSS I don't think your right there. When either `Person` or `Event` is instantiated, `_Endpoint` is set and is available in the `BaseClass`.

Comment: Test it out - create a `New Person` then a `New Event` and then check each value of `Endpoint` on the two objects

Comment: @SSS I just did. I put `_Endpoint = "/Person"` in `Sub New()` in `Person` and `_Endpoint = "/Event"` in `Sub New()` in `Event` then performed a retrieve of each and the endpoints were correct. I'd agree with you if the `_Endpoint` assignments were in a `Shared Sub New()` as they would be assigned only once and would overwrite each other. Also, just adding `Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)()` is all you need to trigger the assignments.

Comment: After you've created `oEvent`, the `oPerson.EndPoint` property should be "/Event" with the code you've provided.

Comment: @SSS Yes, agreed; in the code provided, that is true but only because `Event` is called last. I don't care what the `Endpoint` property is set to within the objects (they're disposable) because it's changed whenever the class is used to make a call. All I want to do is get the endpoint for the from the type (class) in a generic procedure (`Retrieve`). [I'm getting "discussion' warnings from SO so won't respond here again. I'll update the question with a solution.] Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `EndPoint` to be different for each subclass, you should use `MustOverride` instead of `Shared`...

```
MustInherit Class BaseClass
  Public MustOverride Property EndPoint As String
End Class
```

Then return a constant in each subclass

```
Class Person
  Inherits BaseClass
  Public Overrides Property EndPoint As String
    Get
      Return "/Person"
    End Get
```

You might want to declare `EndPoint` as `ReadOnly` too.

The small limitation is that you'll need an instance of the class to access `EndPoint` (since it isn't `Shared`). If you have a parameterless constructor, you could use `(New Person).EndPoint` where needed.